# Using script to download a file

Tags: scripts, downloads

I'm interested in creating a script that makes no use of `wget` which downloads a file from a specified link . The download should be saved as `world.o` in the folder `/tmp`.
Can anybody walk me through this ? I'm really new with scripting.

Comment: I am confused. Are you asking for a solution that does not use wget?

Comment: That's exactly right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use curl. Make a file that contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -o target/path/filename URL
```

Where target/path/filename is the folder you want to save it to `/tmp` and URL is your specified link.

So

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -o /tmp/world.o http://example.com/your.file
```

If curl is not installed, you can install it with `sudo apt-get install curl`.